# Is that possible in some cases linear regression perform better than complex non-linear methods such as RF, ANN,

Tags: r, regression, lm

is there any reason for simple linear regression to perform better compare to nonlinear models such as RF,cubist and ann?

i have a data set which using linear regression gives better performance compare to those non linear one.

Answer (score 1):

Of course a linear regression algo can perform better than non linear algo sometimes.If the data has a linear relation its obvious that a linear regression model will work better

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for some simple real-world datasets may sometimes be best modeled by a linear relationship. For example the Price of a house and its size are well modeled using a linear relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you define as "better performance", how complex are the methods you're comparing linear regression to and your sample size.